# Erro ao usar "this"

Tags: java, android, android-context

[image: Nao consigo resolver as permissões Action_call]

Estou tentando implementar um código com discagem direta utilizando Action_call no android studio mas esta dando erro no this  e não consigo resolver , alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Tenta colocar o nome da classe. ```Lista_Farmacia.this```

Comment: Poderia [edit] sua pergunta e colocar o código? Imagens dificultam a reprodução do erro, dessa forma mais gente poderá ajudar-lhe

Comment: Foi resolvido colocando a classe Lista-farmacia antes do this.Obrigado ranaral.